# A column in dataframe is automatically converted to float type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this
[image]

and when I apply a function on it like this
median = Top15['% Renewable'].median(axis=0)

```
def func(Top15):
    if (Top15['% Renewable'] >= median):
        Top15['HighRenew'] = 1
    else:
        Top15['HighRenew'] = 0
    return Top15
Top15.apply(func,axis=1)
```

The Rank column is converted to float and I don't know why it is
[image]

Comment: screenshots of your data, are not useful, please take the time to add a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I cannot simulate your problem.

I think better is compare to boolean mask and convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) `True` as `1` and `False` to `0`:

```
Top15['Rank'] = (Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median(axis=0)).astype(int)
```

Main reason why avoid `apply` (if possible) are loops under the hood.

**Sample**:

```
Top15 = pd.DataFrame({'% Renewable':[10,23,56,78,90],
                      'Rank':[10,20,30,4,50]})
print (Top15)
#Top15 = pd.concat([Top15] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
   % Renewable  Rank
0           10    10
1           23    20
2           56    30
3           78     4
4           90    50

median = Top15['% Renewable'].median(axis=0)


def func(x):
    if (x['% Renewable'] >= median):
        x['HighRenew'] = 1
    else:
        x['HighRenew'] = 0
    return x
Top15  = Top15.apply(func,axis=1)

Top15['Rank2'] = (Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median(axis=0)).astype(int)
print (Top15)
   % Renewable  Rank  HighRenew  Rank2
0           10    10          0      0
1           23    20          0      0
2           56    30          1      1
3           78     4          1      1
4           90    50          1      1
```

**Timings**:

```
Top15 = pd.DataFrame({'% Renewable':[10,23,56,78,90],
                      'Rank':[10,20,30,4,50]})
print (Top15)
Top15 = pd.concat([Top15] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [49]: %timeit Top15.apply(func,axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 595 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit (Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median(axis=0)).astype(int)
The slowest run took 5.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 346 µs per loop
```

Comment: Also if you could tell me why Rank column is getting converted to float type in my sample

Comment: @Shankar_edu - Is problem  also with my solution? Maybe some NaNs values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use astype 
Top15['Rank']=Top15.Rank.astype(int)
Or
Top15['Rank']=Top15.Rank.astype(object)